# PHP cURL output is truncated

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, truncated

I am trying to load a `JS` file with `cURL`, but the result is getting truncated. I also tried `file_get_contents` and it still truncates.
But I can access `.js` file directly from browser. There isn't anything in the `request headers` except `user agent` and `referer`, which I included in `curl request`.

What is going on? Is the server messing with me?

Comment: How big is the filesize after the truncation?

Comment: It's a small file about 200 lines (15kb), and it truncates after after about 150 lines.

Comment: In your code, on line 15 you are missing the last line of the file.... Just kidding, how should we tell you without seeing your code?

Comment: The plain `file_get_contents` is not working there's nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the browser wasn't showing full code. I `echoed` the output inside `<script>` tag, and it was appending `DOM` elements. Then I split the output into parts and was sure it wasn't being truncated.